# How to link RCTCameraRoll for Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use the `CameraRoll` library, but [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html) does not specify how to link it for Android. Instead, it only contains [steps for iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html). It states that Android is supported but I have no idea how to link it in order to use it.

Comment: Have you tried using it without linking? It might only require doing it for iOS

Comment: @MattAft Doesn't work if you don't link it. Anyway I moved on to `react-native-image-picker` and it worked much better than `CameraRoll`.

Comment: This works for me on Android without linking.  Maybe in newer versions of react-native?  (@ 0.51.0, cli 2.0.1).

Comment: @JoshuaR. It’s possible that they have changed the library such that it’s not necessary anymore to manually link it before using.

Comment: It seems inconsistent that it would have to be deliberately linked for iOS and not for Android.  React-native growing pains, I guess.

Comment: @JoshuaR. I should also add that the version I was using before I believe was 0.47.

Answer (score -1):

I came thru the same question. The fact is

We have to create a project using React Init method then it automatically created Android and IOS folder.

Later you can install and link the Native libraries automatically. Here are the code snippets.

react-native init Cameraroll

npm i react-native-camera --save

react-native link

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
        <Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
          <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
        </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }
  takePicture() {
    const options = {};
    //options.location = ...
    this.camera.capture({metadata: options})
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
}
```

Useful links
https://github.com/chrisbianca/react-native-cameraroll#install

Comment: This answer doesn't answer my question. In fact, you are installing and linking a different module.